# change beg or end of an object containing TRUE and FALSE

Tags: r

I have the following expressions that produces a vector of TRUE and FALSE

```
z3<- data.frame(z2[2:length(z2)])
S<-runif(nrow (z3))<=0.99

TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

I tranform the last item in the resulting vector to FALSE to include in the below expressions for which I use

```
S[11]<-FALSE 
while(S[11] [!FALSE]) {S<-runif(nrow (X))<=0.99}
train<-print(S)
```

I would like to transform into FALSE the last item of TRUE/FALSE list above by using a head /tail expression, however when I do it produces the following error

```
head(S,1)<-FALSE 
Error en head(S, 1) <- FALSE : no se pudo encontrar la función "head<-"
```

Is there a way to use head/tail or another expression as for the train<-print to return the last item as FALSE

Comment: Why do you have to use the `head` or `tail` function? Why not regular indexing?

Comment: Why not simply use `S[length(S)] <- FALSE` and in base R there's no `tail<-` or `head<-` functions

Comment: Indexing - because the length of the TRUE and FALSE varies (this is an example and because several FALSE TRUE objects are produced which makes repeating manual indexing not optimal

Comment: Your code is invalid syntactically in many places.  From you comment, it's not clear that you understand that each `TRUE` or `FALSE` is a single element in your object `S` . Perhaps you can post what you want `S` to look like after your "transformation" and we can suggest code.